# Can I use the mice package to impute two different kinds of missing at once?

Tags: r, r-mice

I have two types of missing data in my data set of 30 continuous independent variables and one binary dependent variable. One type of missing is just missing at random.

The other type of missing is when the value is left-censored. We can assume a log-normal distribution for these. No negative raw values. This I can also do with mice and the qgcomp package ([see here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/qgcomp/html/mice.impute.leftcenslognorm.html)).

The problem is doing both of these at the same time. Let's say I have 100 observations and some are missing an independent variable randomly, while others are missing the left-censored data. How can I impute both of these types of missing at once to get 100 imputed data sets (instead of imputing one type and then the other ending up with 1000 data sets).

```
set.seed(123)
data<-matrix(rlnorm(100*30), ncol=30)
data[sample(length(data), round(0.02*length(data)))] <- NA   #Missing at random
data[sample(length(data), round(0.05*length(data)))] <- "LC" #Left censored
Y<-rbinom(n=100,size=1,prob=0.4)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(data,Y))
```